# how to solve ansible unknown url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, ansible, prometheus-node-exporter

roles/tasks/main.yml code

```
- name: Download and unpack node exporter binary to /usr/local/bin
unarchive:
src: https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/releases/download/v1.2.2/node_exporter-1.2.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
dest: /usr/local/bin/
remote_src: yes
extra_opts: [--strip-components=1]
owner: "ec2-user"
group: "ec2-user"
```

node-exporter.yml code

```
---
- hosts: node-exporter
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
   - roles
```

error message

```
fatal: [ip]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failure downloading https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/releases/download/v1.2.2/node_exporter-1.2.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz, Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>"}
```

if I run "ansible -m ping node-exporter", I receive pong. and "ping www.google.com" working well

but, this code not working

Help me how to solve this problem or recommend me any code ....

(I use amazon linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something weird is happening there. At your role code you have `https://github.com/` and in the error `ssh://github.com`, are you sure that you are using the last version of your code or something like that?

Comment: I accidentally uploaded the wrong error code. I modified it.

Comment: It can be a DNS problem. Can you try `dig github.com`?

Comment: thank you !!  target server does not set DNS

Comment: Yep. That's what I thought. Add Google DNS "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" to your resolver and you should have your problem solved. Please up vote my comments and my answer if it helped you to figured out your issue.

Comment: Thanks! Is it solved? Can you please share the solution?

Comment: I added DNS host name in my AWS VPC.